# How to remove an object and all its relationships from the objects its related to in coredata

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, core-data

[image]

The blue Table is called `Routine` and the other one is called `Exercise`.

`Routine.exercise` has a `Many-to-Many` relationship with `Exercise.routine`.

I want to delete a Routine and I want all exercises to be disassociated (break the relationship) with that routine.

I understand how to remove a routine from an exercise `[myExercise removeObjectRoutine:myRoutine]` and how to delete a routine from coredata.

Currently the code I am working with fetches the associated `Exercises` to the `Routine` Object and then removes the routine from each exercise one by one in a for loop.

I wonder if there is a more efficient way to do this, if I delete a routine it automatically deletes all associations with that object?.
 Meaning I have Routine A that is associated with Exercise A,B & C. If I delete Routine A, then Exercise A, B & C association with Routine A are deleted too.

I am quite new to objective-c and core data hope anyone can help.

Comment: Have you configured the deletion rules on your bi-directional relationship? See 'Relationship Delete Rules' https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdRelationships.html

Comment: Great, I posted the answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to configure the deletion rules on your bi-directional relationship. See 'Relationship Delete Rules' [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdRelationships.html) for a description of the options.